# Focus in a field of subform from main form

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a button in the main form which adds a value to the sub-form. I want to then set focus on the "quantity" field in the added record in the subform, but following the other questions and instructions I found online does not seem to work. If you could fill me in why the following code does not work that would be great!

```
Private Sub insertAtPrice(price)
    DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord
    DoCmd.SetWarnings False
    Dim SQl As String
    ' Invoice Code Item Retail Quant Wholesale Total
    SQl = "INSERT INTO ORDERLINE ( Invoice, Code, Item, Cost, Quant, Price) VALUES ('" & Me.Invoice.value & "', '000Y1', 'Fruit/Veg', " & price & ".00\2, 1, " & price & ".00)"
    DoCmd.RunSQL SQl
    DoCmd.SetWarnings True
    Me.AINVOICELINE_subform.Requery
    'Focus into quantity of new record
    With Me.AINVOICELINE_subform.Form.RecordsetClone
        .FindFirst "Key = " & DMax("[Key]", "ORDERLINE")
        If .NoMatch Then 'just in case another user deleted it in the interim
          MsgBox "Record not found!", vbCritical
        Else 'go to that record
          Me.AINVOICELINE_subform.Form.Bookmark = .Bookmark
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: If the question is about Access VBA then why was it tagged VB.NET and not VBA? Please read the descriptions of the tags you're using and know what language you are writing your code in.

Comment: "Doesn't work" means what - error message, wrong result, nothing happens? Are Cost and Price text fields?

Comment: To clarify, it means no error message but nothing is focused. The line -Me.AINVOICELINE_subform.Form.Bookmark = .Bookmark- is run through the debugger but does not do anything. Attempting to use SetFocus throws errors as commented below.

All fields are text fields other than Quant, the insert works correctly and so does the Requery. It is only SetFocus which throws errors and Bookmark which does not function

Answer (score 0):

How do you set the focus in the field? After inserting the new record you have to call

```
Me.AINVOICELINE_subform.Form!quantity.SetFocus
```

Alternatively you can edit the tab order of your form controls so that the quantity field gets the focus first and disable the TabStop property for fields you to not need to be focusable.

Comment: So this is what I tried, but (after changing quantity to Quant as it is in the DB) I get the error "Object does not support this property or method" and when I remove Quantity to just select the form with Me.AINVOICELINE_subform.Form.SetFocus I get "There is an invalid method in an expression" error. This is after the End With line. 
This is what is getting me stumped.